# javascript - Need onclick to go full distance before click works again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript function I use that when clicked goes a certain distance. This is used within a scroller going left to right that uses about 7 divs. My question is how do I get the click to go the full distance first before the click can be used again? The issue is if the user rapidly clicks on the arrow button it resets the distance and sometimes can end up in the middle of an image instead of right at the seam. What code am I missing to accomplish this?

```
$(function () {  

    $("#right, #left").click(function () {
        var dir = this.id == "right" ? '+=' : '-=';
        $(".outerwrapper").stop().animate({ scrollLeft: dir + '251' }, 1000);
    });

});
```

Comment: why don't you disable and enable in your javascript function?

Comment: @Krishna I don't know how to do that

Comment: You can do $(this).prop('disabled',true) & then false at the end..

Comment: do you mind showing me with the script I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would've thought that the easiest way would be to have a boolean flag indicating whether or not the animation is taking place:

```
$(function () {

    var animating = false,
        outerwrap = $(".outerwrapper");

    $("#right, #left").click(function () {
        if (animating) {return;}
        var dir = (this.id === "right") ? '+=' : '-=';
        animating = true;
        outerwrap.animate({
            scrollLeft: dir + '251'
        }, 1000, function () {
            animating = false;
        });
    });

});
```

works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/BYossarian/vDtwy/4/

Answer (score 3):

Use .off() to unbind the click as soon as it occurs, then re-bind it once the animation completes.

```
function go(elem){
    $(elem).off('click'); console.log(elem);
    var dir = elem.id == "right" ? '+=' : '-=';
    $(".outerwrapper").stop().animate({ left: dir + '251' }, 3000, function(){
        $("#right, #left").click(go);
    });
}
$("#right, #left").click(function () {
    go(this);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ekx5k/)**

You can see in this simplified example that the click event is unbound immediately after clicking, and then rebound once the animation completes.

Comment: hmm tried this one too and it just shut off the clicking altogether

Comment: You mean the fiddle example didn't work? Works for me. If it works there but not in your code then something else is wrong.

Comment: no the fiddle works fine but not in my site, give a me a bit and let me see if I did something wrong. Nothing is coming up in errors yet

Comment: I get an error at where you have a single } so I added }); and there are no errors but still doesnt work

Comment: this is what I have function go(elem) {
    $(elem).off('click'); console.log(elem);
    var dir = elem.id == "rightboxsolo" ? '+=' : '-=';
    $(".allsolo").stop().animate({ left: dir + '985' }, 1000, function () {
        $("#rightboxsolo, #leftboxsolo").click(go);
    });
}
    $("#rightboxsolo, #leftboxsolo").click(function(){
        go(this);
});

Comment: I've tried different variations but for some reason the click event doesn't even work now. Your fiddle and the code you pasted is different. I tried both but still doesn't work.

Comment: No, the code in my answer and in the jsFiddle are identical. The only difference is that jsFiddle automatically wraps the code inside a document ready call. Are you calling the code from within the document ready?

Answer (score 2):

Use an automatic `then` call like this

```
var isMoving = false;
$(function () {  

  $("#right, #left").click(function () {
    if (isMoving) return;
    isMoving = true;

    var dir = this.id == "right" ? '+=' : '-=';
    $(".outerwrapper").stop().animate({ scrollLeft: dir + '251' }, 1000).then(function(){isMoving = false}());
  });

});
```

Comment: Might need a little massaging.  Don't give up so easily!

Answer (score 2):

I think that you miss the fact that when you make stop() you actually position the slider at some specific point. I.e. if your scroller is 1000px and you click *left* twice very quickly you will probably get

```
scrollLeft: 0 - 251
scrollLeft: -2 - 251
```

So, I think that you should use an index and not exactly these += and -= calculations. For example:

```
$(function () {  

    var numberOfDivs = 7;
    var divWidth = 251;
    var currentIndex = 0;
    $("#right, #left").click(function () {
        currentIndex = this.id == "right" ? currentIndex+1 : currentIndex-1;
        currentIndex = currentIndex < 0 ? 0 : currentIndex;
        currentIndex = currentIndex > numberOfDivs ? numberOfDivs : currentIndex;
        $(".outerwrapper").stop().animate({ scrollLeft: (currentIndex * divWidth) + "px" }, 1000);
    });

});
```

A big benefit of this approach is that you are not disabling the clicking. You may click as many times as you want and you can do that quickly. The script will still works.

Answer (score 1):

This will work perfectly fine:

```
var userDisplaysPageCounter = 1;
    $('#inventory_userdisplays_forward_button').bind('click.rightarrowiventory', function(event) {
        _goForwardInInventory();
    }); 
    $('#inventory_userdisplays_back_button').bind('click.leftarrowiventory', function(event) {
        _goBackInInventory();
    });



function _goForwardInInventory()
{
    //$('#inventory_userdisplays_forward_button').unbind('click.rightarrowiventory');
    var totalPages = $('#userfooterdisplays_list_pagination_container div').length;
    totalPages = Math.ceil(totalPages/4);
//  alert(totalPages);
    if(userDisplaysPageCounter < totalPages)
    {
        userDisplaysPageCounter++;
        $( "#userfooterdisplays_list_pagination_container" ).animate({
            left: "-=600",
            }, 500, function() {

        });
    }

}

function _goBackInInventory()
{
    //$('#inventory_userdisplays_back_button').unbind('click.leftarrowiventory');
    if(userDisplaysPageCounter > 1)
    {
        userDisplaysPageCounter--;
        $( "#userfooterdisplays_list_pagination_container" ).animate({
            left: "+=600",
            }, 500, function() {

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: This will prevent the click event from being triggered if the animation is currently running?

Comment: It will make sure that the animation happens only if the conditions are met.I was working on the same kind of thing two days ago

Answer (score 1):

I second [BYossarian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18966254/86072).

Here is a variation on his demo, which "skips" the animation when the user clicks several times quickly on the buttons :

```
$(function () {

    var targetScroll = 0,
        outerwrap = $(".outerwrapper");

    $("#right, #left").click(function () {
        // stop the animation,
        outerwrap.stop();
        // hard set scrollLeft to its target position
        outerwrap.scrollLeft(targetScroll*251);

        if (this.id === "right"){
            if (targetScroll < 6) targetScroll += 1;
            dir = '+=251';
        } else {
            if (targetScroll > 0) targetScroll -=1;
            dir = '-=251';
        }
        outerwrap.animate({ scrollLeft: dir }, 1000);
    });

});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vDtwy/3/)