# jQuery: horizontal scroll to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

What I'm aiming to achieve in the end in something similar to the bbc site: http://www.bbc.co.uk with a side scroll from section to section. Here's my code and I'll explain the problem I'm facing:
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/kzQFQ/2/ 
HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="contentContainer red"></div>
        <div class="contentContainer blue"></div>
        <div class="contentContainer orange"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="left">LEFT</div>
<div class="right">RIGHT</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.right').click(function () {
        $('.container').animate({
            'left': '-100%'
        });
    });
    $('.left').click(function () {
        $('.container').animate({
            'left': '0%'
        });
    });    
});
```

Firstly I don't know if it's possible to stack the `.contentContainer` divs next to each other without having to set a 300% width on the `.container` div. As the site is going to be CMS I don't want to keep changing the width of the `.container` div to suit. There will only ever be one `.contentContainer` div in view at one time too, thus I've set the overflow to hidden.
I can't seem to figure out a nice scroll function too, the one I have currently only scrolls the `.container` div once by 100%, ideally I'd want this to work more like a slideshow, i.e. on a loop, if possible. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you use a slider plugin? You can even [write your own](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-infinite-carousel/).

Comment: I answered something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18966254/1937302

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/kzQFQ/3/)** . With the code below you can count how many elements you got inside your slider and thereafter set the % width automatically.

```
var length = $('div .container').children('div .contentContainer').length;
$(".container").width(length*100 +'%');
```